# How do I get debug info out of the Intel i40e driver

Tags: drivers, network-interface

We have a system (Ubuntu 18.04) with a couple of Intel X710 4-port NICs in it (Intel `i40e` driver 2.1.14-k). Connected to one of the ports is a device that auto-negotiates at 100Mbit/s, which is supported by the card, and works as intended right up until the device is power-cycled. At this point the link remains up (`ip link` and `ethtool` show it as connected) but no traffic is flowing.

It's not the specific port or NIC, but this doesn't occur on a 1gbit NIC (`igb` driver). We can fix it by physically re-seating the cable, but *not* by using `ip link set down/up` or unloading and reloading the entire kernel module.

The only other symptom we see is when the device is power-cycled, `ethtool -S` on the port increments its `rx_error` count by 3.`tcpdump` doesn't show these frames, so we're assuming the frames are dropped before the driver can pass them up.

I think the root of this is an interaction between the device and the card, and I'd like to see if we can make any further headway by enabling the debug parameter on the driver. From `modinfo i40e`:

```
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all), Debug mask (0x8XXXXXXX) (uint)
```

I'm not sure how to set this correctly, though. So far, I've tried

```
modprobe i40e debug=0x0000FFFF / debug=16 / debug=0x8000000F / debug=0xFFFFFFFF
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-130-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/i40e/i40e.ko debug=0x0000FFFF
```

Looking at the driver source, debug messages come via `pr_info()` calls, but all I see in kern.log/syslog is the usual dmesg logging as the interface comes up. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Are you unloading the module first?

I believe that you have to use

modprobe -r i40e

to remove it, then you can load it again with the parameters.
I found this article helpful (it should be similar on Ubuntu):

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Setting_Module_Parameters.html

This will probably break your connection if you are logged in using one of the interfaces using this driver! :)

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't mention that, but I have been unloading the driver each. (Thankfully I can log in via an igb-driven 1gb interface, so I'm not pulling the rug out from under my own feet :) ). The most annoying thing is that I can't see what the currently set value is so I can't even check if my attempts are having any effect.

Comment: I'm trying to get this working on a system of mine too, will update if I get it working.

I have been using these commands the check what parameters are loaded for various kernel modules:
https://serverfault.com/a/389965/455239